# Extremely unequal sample size in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does an unbalanced sample matter when doing logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6067/does-an-unbalanced-sample-matter-when-doing-logistic-regression)

I’m hoping for help on dealing with unequal sample sizes for logistic regression analysis. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

I’m currently working with data from two types of media user (single media user: N=182 and multiple media user: N=1963). We will be using demographics (such as age, gender, and race) to predict these two types of media user.

So basically, my DV is 0=single media user and 1= multiple media user, and my IVs are age (continuous), gender (dichotomous) and race (dichotomous). However, due to the extremely unequal size of the two categories of my DV, I doubt if I can still use SPSS to run logistic regression. Or maybe it's not a problem that I should worry about?

Thanks so much for answering in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site.

There are several similar questions already on this site:
e.g.
[Sample size for unequal groups in logistic regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22328/sample-size-for-unequal-groups-in-logistic-regression)

and

[Does an unbalanced sample matter when doing logistic regression?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6067/does-an-unbalanced-sample-matter-when-doing-logistic-regression)

Do these answer your question? If not, please say what other information you need.